# How can I create a single read stream from two files in Node?

Tags: node.js, fs, sax, node-streams

I'm pretty new to NodeJS streams and fileStreams. I'm trying to parse two XML files using SAX. I've succeeded in getting it to work for a single file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sax = require("sax");

const saxStream = sax.createStream(IS_STRICT, OPTIONS);
saxStream.on("error", function (e) { ... });
...
const out = fs.createReadStream(INFILE).pipe(saxStream);
```

How can I pipe two files into SAX?

---

### Update

I'm trying to put the output of SAX into a single file. Here's the SAX I'm using, which is an XML parser that uses streams:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sax

Comment: Pipe them to sax one after the other?

Comment: @jfriend00, sounds promising! How do I do that?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  SAX is an XML parser, right?  So, what type of output do you want with two inputs?  Which SAX library are you using (please provide NPM link to the exact module)?

Comment: @jfriend00, I updated the question with answers to your questions. Please let me know if you need to know anything else.

Comment: Please link to the NPM module you're using, not a compressed archive.  We want to see the documentation and online source code, not download and decompress something.  The idea here is for you to make it as easy for people to help you as possible.  The more difficult it is, the fewer people will go to that level of trouble to try to help.

Comment: So, you just want to combine sequentially the output from two inputs into the same file?

Comment: @jfriend00, okay, I updated the link. Yes, I want to feed two files into SAX sequentially, and to have the output directed to a single output file.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried coding a way to do this, but the SAX parser only accepts one root node in the XML input so once it's done with the first file, it ignores all the XML in a 2nd XML you feed it because it's outside the root node.

So, if you want to parse the 2nd file, it looks like you need to create a 2nd `sax.createStream()` and feed it the 2nd file.  As always, we could offer you a more complete suggestion if you showed us what you're actually trying to do with the parsed XML input.

FYI, here's what I tried:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sax = require("sax");

const saxStream = sax.createStream(false, {trim: true, normalize: true});

saxStream.on("error", e => { 
    console.log("saxStream error", e);
});

saxStream.on("opentag", node => {
    console.log(node);
});

saxStream.on("end", () => {
    console.log("done with saxStream");
})


let stream1 = fs.createReadStream("./sample1.xml");
stream1.pipe(saxStream, {end: false});
stream1.on("end", () => {
    console.log("starting stream2")
    fs.createReadStream("./sample2.xml").pipe(saxStream, {end: true});
});
```

I stepped through the parser in the debugger and the 2nd file's input is successfully fed into the SAX parser, it just ignores it because it's outside of the root node.

There are several places in [this file](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/blob/master/lib/sax.js#L1030) where it checks for `parser.closedRoot` and if so, it skips the content.

---

Actually, I did get it to work by adding a fake root tag that could enclose both sets of XML.  I have no idea if this is what you want, but you can examine this for educational purposes:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sax = require("sax");

const saxStream = sax.createStream(false, {trim: true, normalize: true});

saxStream.on("error", e => { 
    console.log("saxStream error", e);
});

saxStream.on("opentag", node => {
    console.log(node);
});

saxStream.on("end", () => {
    console.log("done with saxStream");
})


let stream1 = fs.createReadStream("./sample1.xml");
let stream2 = fs.createReadStream("./sample2.xml");
saxStream.write("<fakeTop>");
stream1.pipe(saxStream, {end: false});
stream1.on("end", () => {
    console.log("starting stream2")
    stream2.pipe(saxStream, {end: false});
    stream2.on("end", () => {
        saxStream.write("</fakeTop>");
        saxStream.end();
    });
});
```